# More elegant way to match after HashMap-value than cloning it

Tags: caching, hash, rust

I'm learning Rust using [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch01-00-introduction.html). I'm working on the following task in the [chapter dealing with closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch13-01-closures.html):

> Try modifying `Cacher` to hold a hash map rather than a single value. The keys of the hash map will be the `arg` values that are passed in, and the values of the hash map will be the result of calling the closure on that key. Instead of looking at whether `self.value` directly has a `Some` or a `None` value, the value function will look up the `arg` in the hash map and return the value if it's present. If it's not present, the `Cacher` will call the closure and save the resulting value in the hash map associated with its `arg` value.

This is my solution:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Cacher<T>
where
    T: Fn(i32) -> i32,
{
    calculation: T,
    values: HashMap<i32, i32>,
}

impl<T> Cacher<T>
where
    T: Fn(i32) -> i32,
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            values: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
    fn value(&mut self, arg: i32) -> i32 {
        match self.values.get(&arg) {
            Some(v) => *v,
            None => {
                let v = (self.calculation)(arg);
                self.values.insert(arg, v);
                v
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compiler error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.values` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:26:17
   |
22 |         match self.values.get(&arg) {
   |               ----------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
26 |                 self.values.insert(arg, v);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
29 |         }
   |         - immutable borrow ends here
```

I can solve this by using:

```
match self.values.clone().get(&arg) { ...
```

Do I really need to clone the whole `HashMap` to use it in the match-statement and inserting a value afterwards?

Comment: `let c = &self.calculation; *self.values.entry(arg).or_insert_with(|| (c)(arg))`

Comment: A more verbose way without introducng variable `c`: `use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;let v = match self.values.entry(arg) {
             Entry::Occupied(o) => o.into_mut(),
             Entry::Vacant(v) => v.insert( (self.computation)(arg) ),
        };

        *v`